# Multiple close reasons no longer shown

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116662/differences-when-writing-code-for-arm-vs-x86) as "unclear what you are asking".

The display showed 4 existing close votes for "primarily opinion based".

The notice posted to the user was then for the majority message "primarily opinion based", and indicates that I voted with the majority, which is incorrect.

OK, so this puts words in my mouth and might dissuade people from voting, which is not good.

But the bigger problem is that in only showing the majority "on hold" reason, it doesn't help the OP fully see what kinds of editing the question might require to be a reasonable question.

I am pretty sure there was a meta on this earlier, because there used to be multiple close reasons on some posts for a while.

Has opinion changed at all as to whether providing only one close reason to readers is a good practice?

Comment: They probably saw *coding style* and immediately went to VTC.

Comment: There are only multiple close reasons shown when there are multiple Off-Topic subtypes (Tool Recommendations, Belongs on Super User, etc).  For the main types majority always wins

Comment: What I saw is that some combinations of CV show up as multiple reasons, but most combinations go with "majority wins"... Yes, would be nice to have this clarified.

Comment: Related on MSE: [When is the list of the users who selected a close reason shown?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188688/when-is-the-list-of-the-users-who-selected-a-close-reason-shown/188706#188706).  Additionally [Don't choose the best close reason, allow multiple close reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185983/dont-choose-the-best-close-reason-allow-multiple-close-reasons) is a Feature Request to modify the behavior you don't like.

Comment: That feature request is a year old.  With only a few votes, I have to guess it didn't gather enough steam.

Comment: @ChrisF not entirely true.  When multiple off-topic reasons are picked (and off-topic is in the majority), it will show all of them and who voted to close for each reason

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Oh, ignore me. I'm not fully awake this morning.

Comment: @Paul I think there are more discussions on MSE that I couldn't find.  However, we don't have one here on MSO.  If you feel that strongly about it, then maybe a feature request here is in order.

Comment: @Paul here's the more highly upvoted (and older) feature request: [Distinguish votes to close by reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason)

Comment: A feature request requires consensus, rather than one person feeling strongly.  There is a potential morass here.  If 5 votes are required to match on reasons, it will make it more difficult to close down bad questions. If it is exposed that people wanted to close a question for 5 different reasons, the site can look schizo.  The message could be changed slightly instead without disclosing all the reasons, i.e. "the top reason cited was blah: explanation,"  which gets rid of part of the mis-reporting.  Or there could be multiple messages.... and let dice fall where they may.

Comment: It does seem my post is a duplicate of [Distinguish close votes by reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason) (MSE) from 4 years ago. The top answer looks pretty good as a method to implement.