# I gave a different close reason yet the system lists me

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, closed-questions

Give a close reason. Later, when there's enough close votes the page shows your name next to the reason, even though you gave a different one.

Here's an example: [In how many ways you can count till N using the numbers <= with N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404024/in-how-many-ways-you-can-count-till-n-using-the-numbers-with-n)

It's definitely not a duplicate and I feel quite *offended* that the page shows that I gave that reason.

Comment: Related: [Why is only 1 reason displayed on closed questions when different reason votes were cast for it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181870/why-is-only-1-reason-displayed-on-closed-questions-when-different-reason-votes-w), [Distinguish votes to close by reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason)

Comment: [Could the close vote banner please be made less… well, wrong?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172654/could-the-close-vote-banner-please-be-made-less-well-wrong "duplicate feature request at MSE")

Comment: It could be phrased as "X, Y, and Z voted to close for reason ...., A and B also voted to close.". The current system has effectively misquoted me, by claiming my support for a close reason with which I disagree.

Comment: Or "Closed by X, Y, Z, A, and B. The majority close reason was ...." if there is some reason not to say which people voted for the majority reason.

Comment: I haven't got the logic, but there are combinations of CVs that are split listed. There are others where our name is not listed if we choose a different reason... The whole thing seems confusing.

Comment: related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260145/multiple-close-reasons-no-longer-shown

Comment: I've been hit by this too... it's frustrating.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281755/my-offtopic-close-vote-is-now-presented-as-duplicate

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I disagree on the _majority_ part of the text. I just saw two people (me and x) vote as off-topic, but a user with privilege to close questions alone marked the question as dup, guess what was chosen as the close reason? Yep, dup of ...

Comment: My Meta Question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374304/wrong-marking-shown-when-closing-question was CLOSED as duplicate pointing to this 2014 question. When will this be fixed !?