# My "offtopic" close vote is now presented as "duplicate"

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I've recently voted to close a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774426/how-to-parse-nested-element-xml-in-jaxb) as "offtopic" (from my PoV the OP did not provide relevant code).

Now the question is marked as duplicate with the following notice:

> marked as duplicate by *lexicore*, Another User, Yet Another User 2 hours ago

Hm... Well I've voted to close the question, but from what I remember I think I did not mark it as duplicate. So the quoted statement above does not seem to be correct to me.

Shouldn't it be corrected? For instance:

> marked as duplicate by Yet Another User 2 hours ago
>   with close votes by *lexicore*, Another User

Comment: Must be a duplicate somewhere, but couldn't find it. Let's say it is by design.

Comment: My solution to this problem is never vote to close a question. I intend to stick to that until the system stops misrepresenting close reasons. The message could be trivially reworded to "marked closed by ....., majority reason duplicate.".

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Right, a duplicate, but no (good) answer there. Let's close this one.

Comment: Now this is another one: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer.". It has a *deleted* answer! Grrr...